# StandardScaler returns NaN

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

env:

```
spark-1.6.0 with scala-2.10.4
```

usage:

```
// row of df : DataFrame = (String,String,double,Vector) as (id1,id2,label,feature)
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet("data/Labeled.parquet")
val SC = new StandardScaler()
.setInputCol("feature").setOutputCol("scaled")
.setWithMean(false).setWithStd(true).fit(df) 


val scaled = SC.transform(df)
.drop("feature").withColumnRenamed("scaled","feature")
```

Code as the example here http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#standardscaler

NaN exists in `scaled`, `SC.mean`, `SC.std`

I don't understand why `StandardScaler` could do this even in `mean` or how to handle this situation. Any advice is appreciated.

data size as parquet is 1.6GiB, if anyone needs it just let me know

UPDATE:

Get through the code of `StandardScaler` and this is likely to be a problem of precision of `Double` when `MultivariateOnlineSummarizer` aggregated.

Comment: And also, NaN column in `SC.mean`generates non-NaN result in scaled. Weird.

Comment: Could you add some details? Min  and max over the problematic columns for starters.

Comment: @zero323 (min,max)is (1.5E-5,1.7976931348623157E308) which reminds me of dirty data

Comment: Either that or simply numerical issue. I doubt you can do much better though. If you don't expect overflows you can try converting to decimals and computing mean / sd directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a value equals to `Double.MaxValue` and when `StandardScaler` sum the columns, result overflows.

Simply cast those column to `scala.math.BigDecimal` works.

ref here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I tried when faced the same problem is reseting the index from both os dataframes that I was manipulating, after the standartization procedure:

```
`df = df.reset_index() 
`df_norm = df_norm.reset_index()
```